# Convert mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a column which has dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy. How do I convert it into yyyy-mm-dd format?

Tried this:-
hive> select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('02/22/2015', 'yyyy-mm-dd')));
but it doesn't work

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189790/date-format-conversion-in-hive

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('02/22/2015' ,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace("value", '/' , '-'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) as value
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Rahul's answer.

A little note, if you are trying to convert a whole column, make sure you use all lower case for date format **(mm not MM)**, otherwise all months keeps showing as January.

For example:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(ThedateColumn,'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd') from table;
```