# How to get time of day, day of week, Month from date in Hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I have date in the following format stored in Mailed_Date column

```
Mon, 09/20/10 01:04 PM
```

I have used a serde(csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar) to get this date from a csv file and stored it as a String.
How can i get the time of day, day of week, Month from this date in Hive.

I tried using

```
select HOUR(Mailed_Date) from final3 limit 5;
```

but got a NULL as answer.

Comment: First, you've got to transform that vomitive format into a portable ODBC format i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` which is the only format that Hive supports for *TIMESTAMP*.

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer to my query:-

```
select day(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr(Mailed_Date, 6, 14), 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm'), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm')) from final3 limit5
```

Here first I extract the date and then convert it to the required format which is acceptable by Hive to get the day, month or time from.

Got a hint from the below question:-
[Convert mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053706/convert-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-hive)