# Replace Diff Date Format in a given particular format in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

How to replace different dates such as Jan 11, 2003 | 6/17/1969 | 08/22/54
with a date string in “MM/DD/YY” format during creating table in hive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Format Conversion in Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189790/date-format-conversion-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

Hive won't understand 'Jan 11, 2003' it as a date string. Rest of them you can convert it into by using 'unix_timestamp()'.